# How to apply filter2d to HSL format in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

I want to do filter2d for mat in HLS or HSV format, because it can filter for three channels separately and can easily adjust the brightness and saturation. But the result is completely different from the result of applying filter2d to the RGB format.

```
        cvtColor(mat, mat, COLOR_RGB2HSV)
        val hls = mutableListOf<Mat>()
        split(mat, hls)
//        filter2D(mat, mat, -1, kernel, Point(-1.0, -1.0), 10.0)
        filter2D(hls[0], hls[0], -1, kernel, Point(-1.0, -1.0))
        filter2D(hls[1], hls[1], -1, kernel, Point(-1.0, -1.0))
        filter2D(hls[2], hls[2], -1, kernel, Point(-1.0, -1.0))
        merge(hls, mat)
        cvtColor(mat, mat, COLOR_HSV2RGB)
```

Original and HLS filter2d:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQScn.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IpYP.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think because the conversion of rgb2hsv is nonlinear. Therefore, the results are different.